# How to sort multiple pivot tables in a way that rows with similar names displays together?`

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

I am having 4 pivot tables displayed as below. 
[Pivot Tables Organization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/obY5G.png)

I would like to sort each of them in a way that the rows with similar names displays together.

```
Buddy Subscription       Buddy Subscription       Buddy Subscription      Buddy Subscription
Guest CLient             Guest Client             Guest Client            Guest client
Messaging                Messaging                                        Messaging
Contact Storage                                   Contact Storage
                         BOSH-HTTPSSupport
MUC ROOm                 MUC Room                 Muc Room                Muc Room
```

Comment: Off the top of my head, a quick way might just be to enter dummy data into your main table, allowing the rows to match. I'm not sure if you can "force" the PivotTable to match up rows directly.

Comment: I agree with batman, dummy data is the way to go, then all the tables will have the same number of columns. And sorting each table the same way will result in what you want.